# Docker pipeline build failing after upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have an Azure function that I am upgrading from v3 to v4, as well as upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0.

This Azure function lives in a Docker linux container. It runs effectively on my local machine after the upgrade, but I am running into an issue when hitting this from my Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline build step in my docker file.

```
Step 13/31 : RUN dotnet build "MyProject.Functions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

The actual error it throws is this

```
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : You must install or update .NET to run this application. [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : App: /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/tools/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator.dll [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : Architecture: x64 [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : .NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/ [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : The following frameworks were found: [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :   6.0.10 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App] [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : Learn about framework resolution: [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : To install missing framework, download: [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64 [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
    /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.1.1/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : Metadata generation failed. [/src/MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj]
```

What can I do to get my .NET version updated and have the pipeline build run effectively? The build step before (outside of the docker file) works without any issues. I've tried changing around my docker file as well as changing my agent target to different versions of ubuntu and windows.

Docker File

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj", "MyProject/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Infrastructure/MyProject.Infrastructure.csproj", "MyProject.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Models/MyProject.Models.csproj", "MyProject.Models/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Common.Direct/MyProject.Common.Helpers.csproj", "MyProject.Common.Direct/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.Functions.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.Functions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.Functions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I fixed my problem.

I needed to update my nuget packages as well when upgrading my .NET version.

Don't forget to update your nuget packages!